# How to restore Microsoft root certificates after moving them to untrusted list?

Tags: certificate, windows

I have been experimenting with security options on m my Windows 10 and moved all Microsoft root certificates from trusted into untrusted position. Not sure if that was the problem but my admin privilege is lost. I am still logged in as an administrator but my access to everything "denied by administrator".
I cannot access Registry, cannot install apps, cannot access Task Manager, cannot reset the PC.

Can anybody help to reset everything to default please?

Comment: Are you able to restart and access Safe Mode?

Comment: Yes, I accessed in safe mode and created a new admin account. The new account has all admin privileges. Will work for now. Thanks for your consideration.